# Using batoo without declaring classes in persistence.xml

Tags: jpa-2.0

I want to experiment with new Batoo JPA api.
But I wonder if Batoo also works without defining entity classes in persistence.xml. The testcase org.batoo.jpa.community.test.t1.T1 fails if you delete the  tags (like: org.batoo.jpa.community.test.t1.Service ) from persistence.xml although this Service class is annotated correctly with the @Entity annotation !
I think the latter should be enough for the JPA spec.

Comment: I guess you should have a look at https://github.com/BatooOrg/BatooJPA/issues/75.

Answer (score 0):

No, annotating with @Entity is not guaranteed to be enough in Java SE environment. In JPA 2.0 specification this is told with following words:

> A list of all named managed persistence classes must be specified in
>   Java SE environments to insure portability. Portable Java SE
>   applications should not rely on the other mechanisms described here to
>   specify the managed persistence classes of a persistence unit.
>   Persistence providers may require that the set of entity classes and
>   classes that are to be managed must be fully enumerated in each of the
>   persistence.xml files in Java SE environments.